# Best way for i18n l10n in Android for SQLite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using SQLite to store questions in a trivia-like android game. I have followed the tutorial on using own SQLite database:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

I would like to add i18n functionality, and I wonder if the table `android_metadata` can be used for this (**and how**) or is intended for something else and I would better add a field for i18n.

If `android_metadata` table was to be used: how it could link to each question stored in the QUESTIONS table?

My current database has only one table (apart from android_metadata) with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE "QUESTIONS" (
_id INTEGER, 
question TEXT,
answer TEXT
)
```

Thanks in advance,
Daniel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a field for your the different locales

```
CREATE TABLE "QUESTIONS" (
 _id INTEGER, 
 language TEXT,
 question TEXT,
 answer TEXT
)
```

and use language in the appropriate queries